# If Else logic converting to Select case - Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
IF inputVariable = '0'        
            THEN
            DELETE existingTemptable
            WHERE  status != 999;
        ELSE
            IF inputVariable = '1'    
            THEN
            DELETE existingTemptable
            WHERE  status = 999;  
        ELSE
            DELETE existingTemptable
            WHERE  status != 999
                   AND date < utils.dateadd('MONTH', -6, SYSTIMESTAMP);
            END IF;
        END IF;
```

This **If logic** is present on a temp table and I have to remove the temp table and make it only select query , so approached with WITH CTE  but stuck in the below

what should be in the where clause

```
 with existingTemptable as
    (
    //got the temp table here 
    ), myTable as
    (
      Select * from existingTemptable  
      **where 
      status = CASE WHEN inputVariable = '0' THEN 999 
                                        WHEN inputVariable != '0' AND inputVariable != '1' THEN 999
                                        ELSE status 
                                        END**
    )Select  * from myTable
```

What to put in **WHERE**  clause so that it mimics the If logic above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful if `inputVariable` or `status` (or both) may be `null`. The rest is a direct application of logical rules one learns (or should learn) in middle school.

```
select *
from   existingTemptable
where  inputVariable = '0' and (status  = 999 or status is null)
       or
       inputVariable = '1' and (status != 999 or status is null)
       or
       (inputVariable is null or inputVariable not in ('0', '1'))
            and (status = 999 or status is null) and date >= [whatever]
```

Note - even in the absence of null handling, you can't write the `where` clause with a `case` expression; that's because in one branch you require "not equal", and you can't do it with a simple case expression.